# How to count files separated by null characters, as returned by; find . -type f -print0?

Tags: 20.04, find, xargs

Extract from `man find`:

> `-print0`
>
> True; print the **full file name** on the standard output, **followed by a null character** (instead of the newline character that -print uses). This allows file names that contain newlines or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by programs that process the find output. This option corresponds to the -0 option of xargs.

So if (for example) you wanted to find and trash files older than the newest 10 in a directory, you could use (credit @pLumo):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -rz | sed -z 1,10d | xargs -0 gio trash
```

But how would you count the number of files about to be trashed before this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep`, which can handle lines separated by null characters:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -rz | sed -z 1,10d  | grep -zc .
```

From [`man grep`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/grep.1posix.html):

```
-z, --null-data
      Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a  zero  byte
      (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.  Like the -Z or --null option, this
      option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
```

> So if (for example) you wanted to find and trash files older than the newest 10 in a directory, you could use ...

No, you couldn't. `find`'s output isn't guaranteed to be in order of creation, modification, access, or anything else for that matter (except in that there's an ordering by `-depth`, but that's neither here nor there).

You'd need something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -Vrz | sed -z '1,10d; s/^[[:digit:].]* //'
```

which uses the modification time (printed as a unix timestamp using `%T@`, and sorts by that, using `-V` version sort as a proxy for general floating-point sort, and then  finally removes the timestamp using `sed`.

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to point me to reference material for the printf format codes, as I am unfamiliar with them and have been unable to find them.

Comment: @Broadsworde search for `-printf format` in [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/find.1.html), or look for format directives in the [GNU find docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Format-Directives)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same line and print the number of files after trashing them:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -rz | sed -z 1,10d | xargs -0 bash -c 'gio trash $*;echo $# files trashed'
```

Or you can count the lines independently. Just go back to normal end-of-line (`print` instead `print0` and removing the `-z`).

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | sort -r | sed  1,10d | wc -l
```

Comment: Thank you. That is the way I was previously counting the files before being advised not to rely on the newline separator, as it is also valid as part of a filename.

Comment: I added another possibility, extending the same command line you had.

Comment: I get error: 'gio: No locations given' with the bash -c method

Comment: think its best to do `xargs -0 -I {} sh -c '...' _ {}` or one argument will get shaved off

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on that xargs method please? (confused)

Comment: @Broadsworde are you sure you copied pasted the whole line? Because the `bash` method works alright for me ...

Answer (score 0):

Create an index array with files in descending order; newest file on index 0 or `ls -rt` which will arrange files in ascending order.

```
$ eval "a=($(ls -t --quoting-style=shell-escape))"
```

Print from the nth file to the end:

<sup>(using a descending array with offset `|--|xxxx|` will prevent, for example, a loop from accidentally eating up your files).</sup>

```
$ printf %s\\n "${a[@]:10}"
```

Print from start to the nth file:

```
$ printf %s\\n "${a[@]:0:10}" # or "${a[@]::10}"
                       ^ ^
                  offset length
```

Print nth file from the start:

```
$ printf %s\\n "${a[@]:5:1}"
```

print nth file from the end:

```
$ printf %s\\n "${a[@]:(-5):1}"
```

Print null terminated file list:

```
$ printf %s\\0 "${a[@]:10}" | xargs -0 -n 1
```

Script example how you can use it in a loop;

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

eval "a=($(ls -t --quoting-style=shell-escape))"
for b in "${a[@]:10}"; do
      ls "$b"
done
```